# What type should you use for keeping game score

Tags: xna, c#

Lets say you have a high scoring game like geometry wars, why type would you use for the score and how should you handle overflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the scoring system in your game and the type you use you may never need to wrap. For example, an unsigned 64-bit integer can hold a maximum value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. Long before games get close to that most would start displaying problems rendering a number that long in the UI. It would also take an awfully long time to rack up a score that big so it's not really worth worrying about.

Depending on how you implement a leaderboard (i.e. use a third-party system for online scoreboards) then the format of the score may already be decided for you on their servers.

Comment: I agree. `int` should be sufficient, and `UInt64` should almost never need to be exceeded.

Comment: 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 is the maximum value for a *signed* 64-bit integer. For an unsigned 64-bit integer, the maximum value is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

Comment: You could use the System.Numerics.BigInteger type. It supposedly doesn't have an upper limit (performance will probably degrade if it gets too large).

Comment: @Michael Madsen Doh! Twice as long then before it wraps! ;) Ta

Comment: 18 billion billion is one hell of a score.

Comment: GameCenter on the iOS uses a signed 64-bit int that can be formatted in many ways (points, time, fractions), it seems flexible enough.

Comment: Not applicable to your actual case, but signed integer overflow is undefined in C, so it's probably a good idea to use an unsigned integer there in order to avoid some potential issues.